# Bound on space for selection algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, space-complexity, lower-bounds

There is a well known worst case $O(n)$ [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to find the $k$'th largest element in an array of integers.  It uses a [median-of-medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Properties_of_pivot) approach to find a good enough pivot, partitions the input array in place and then recursively continues in it's search for the $k$'th largest element.

What if we weren't allowed to touch the input array, how much extra space would be needed in order to find the $k$'th largest element in $O(n)$ time?  Could we find the $k$'th largest element in $O(1)$ extra space and still keep the runtime $O(n)$?  For example, finding the maximum or minimum element takes $O(n)$ time and $O(1)$ space.

Intuitively, I cannot imagine that we could do better than $O(n)$ space but is there a proof of this?

Can someone point to a reference or come up with an argument why the $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$'th element would require $O(n)$ space to be found in $O(n)$ time?

Comment: I'm not an expert but perhaps these papers are helpful: [Comparison-Based Time-Space Lower Bounds for Selection](http://www.siam.org/proceedings/soda/2009/SODA09_017_chant.pdf) and 
[Space-time tradeoffs and first order problems in a model of programs](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=804680)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is an open problem if you can do selection with $O(n)$ time and $O(1)$ extra memory cells without changing the input (see [here](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1641-05.pdf)). But you can come pretty close to this.

Munro and Raman proposed an [algorithm for selection](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397595002251) that runs in $O(n^{1+\varepsilon})$ time while using only $O(1/\varepsilon)$ extra storage (cells). This algorithm leaves the input unchanged. You can pick any small $\varepsilon>0$.

At its core, Munro and Raman's algorithm works as the classical $O(n)$ algorithm: It maintains a *left* and *right* bound (called *filter*), which are two elements with known rank. The requested element is contained between the two filters (rank-wise). By picking a good pivot element $p$ we can check all numbers against the filters and $p$. This makes it possible to update the filters and decreases the number of elements left to check (rank-wise). We repeat until we have found the request element.

What is different to the classical algorithm is the choice of $p$. Let $A(k)$ be the algorithm that solves selection for $\varepsilon=1/k$.  The algorithm $A(k)$  divides the array in equally-sized blocks and identifies a block where many elements are, whose ranks are in between the filters (existence by pigeon-hole principle). This block will then be scanned for a good pivot element with help of the algorithm $A(k-1)$. The recursion anchor is the trivial $A(1)$ algorithm. The right block size (and doing the math) gives you running time and space requirements as stated above.

Btw, the algorithms you are looking for, were recently named *constant-work-space algorithms*.

I am not aware of any lower bound.